PHP Sum up fields
I have following multidimensional array in PHP and want to clean it up but also sum up the fields.
Example:
    [UP-IXSZ-RP36] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 1
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => H-11-004
            [name] => Coffee Mate Original
        )

    [PW-KQZA-ROHD] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 4
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => H-14-017
            [name] => Trumpf AK
        )

    [K3-9SV1-MQQO] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 5
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => H-14-017
            [name] => Trumpf AK
        )

    [EN-6BZL-HJIG] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 1
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => B
            [name] => Turm Sahne
        )

    [3M-EEF4-JO4N] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 1
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => H-14-017
            [name] => Trumpf AK
        )

I want to filter by name and it should then show me following array.
Which SKU he uses is not important.
    [UP-IXSZ-RP36] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 1
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => H-11-004
            [name] => Coffee Mate Original
        )

    [PW-KQZA-ROHD] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 10
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => H-14-017
            [name] => Trumpf AK
        )

    [EN-6BZL-HJIG] => Array
        (
            [stueck] => 1
            [anzahl] => 1
            [stock] => B
            [name] => Turm Sahne
        )

Can someone help me with this issue?
Thanks.

Basic methodology - see duplicates. You should be using the name as the "grouping" key in your result array first here, and then replace it with the SKU (which you overwrite while grouping the data) afterwards. For that you can use a combination of array_combine and array_column.
